# Scattering between momentum states in a shallow potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering

So I'm thinking about this problem and I get the impression the solution should be quite simple, but I can't find it anywhere else so I'm wondering if I'm thinking about this wrong. The idea is, suppose you have a relatively shallow potential - no singularities, just a $V(x)$ bounded between two values everywhere - and you want to find the scattering process for high speed particles travelling through it, so that in general if $\Delta V = V_{max} - V_{min}$, then $p^2/2m >> \Delta V$. Now I was thinking that if we consider a short enough propagation time, $\delta t$, then

$$
\langle p_1 | e^{i\frac{\hat{H}}{\hbar}\delta t}|p_0\rangle = 
\langle p_1 | e^{i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar}\frac{\hat{p}^2}{4m}}
 e^{i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar}\hat{V}(x)}
 e^{i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar}\frac{\hat{p}^2}{4m}}|p_0\rangle \approx 
e^{i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar}\frac{(p_o^2-p_1^2)}{4m}} \langle p_1 | 
 1+i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar}\hat{V}(x)|p_0\rangle
$$

and

$$
\langle p_1 |i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar}\hat{V}(x)|p_0\rangle = 
\langle p_1 |x\rangle i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar}V(x)\langle x |p_0\rangle = 
i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar} \mathcal{F}[V]\left(\frac{p_1-p_0}{\hbar}\right)
$$

where $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform, so that

$$
\langle p_1 | e^{i\frac{\hat{H}}{\hbar}\delta t}|p_0\rangle = e^{i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar}\frac{(p_o^2-p_1^2)}{4m}} \left[\delta(p_1-p_0)+i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar} \mathcal{F}[V]\left(\frac{p_1-p_0}{\hbar}\right)\right]
$$

should be the instantaneous matrix connecting all momentum states. Now, am I doing anything wrong? I get the impression the final result can't be quite correct at the very least because it's not Hermitian (since the potential is always a real function, the real part of its Fourier transform is even, which means that the complex part of the matrix here does *not* swap signs upon swapping $p_0$ and $p_1$).

Comment: This, by itself, shouldn't be a problem. Note that $\langle p_1 | e^{i\delta t H} | p_0 \rangle^* = \langle p_0 | e^{-i\delta t H} | p_1\rangle$ so to check that your approximate expression is consistent you also have to change the sign of $\delta t$, and it seems that this is ok

Comment: Oh, ok, so in practice the matrix is Hermitian, it's just that I was going about this wrong, I need to both swap the momenta and change sign to the imaginary terms.

Comment: The matrix is *not* Hermitian, but it doesn't need to be! You calculate transition amplitudes, which are *not* observables (the probabilities are observables). The corresponding operator doesn't need to be Hermitian

Comment: Ok, sorry, you're right, it needs to be *unitary*. I would need to check that.

Comment: When checking it, note that due to your approximation it will be unitary only to leading order in $\delta t$. If I expand $e^{ix}\simeq 1+ix$ and then check if $e^{ix}e^{-ix}=1$ I will get that it is only true up to linear order in $x$

Comment: Right, it makes sense. I need to discard the $\delta t^2$ term or find a way to enforce unitarity otherwise if I use this.